# Query to extract the word from string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle12c

I want to extract words from a  Address field (Oracle 12 C) containing the below address :-

str1: `Abc.. Flat no - 8956, 8th road , Scramendo 4th street,Portland.`
str2: `Abcd.. Flat no Ad- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.`

My query should return

1. `Flat no - 8956.`  (From str1 )
2. `Flat no Ad- 3434/89/69` (From str2)

Basically I want to extract the flat no from the string in huge set of data rows

Comment: What is the end delimiter for the Flat no?  In `str` you have a, and in `str2` you have a space.  Is it either of these?

Comment: I want to extract everything Starting from the Flat no. ....untill the start of the alphabet. Example- in str1 i want to extract -Flat no - 8956,8  and in str2 i want to extract  Flat no Ad- 3434/89/69  which is just before the starting of the word Scramendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below answer can help in resolving the issue -

```
select 
substr(x, instr(x, 'Flat no',1)) from (
select 
--regexp_substr('Abcd.. Flat no- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.', '[[Flat no- ][0-9]*+'),
--substr(
substr(
    'Abcd.. Flat no- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.', 1,
REGEXP_INSTR( 'Abcd.. Flat no- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.',
   '[a-zA-Z]'
 ,instr('Abcd.. Flat no- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.', '-'),1) - 1
 ) x --, instr('Abcd.. Flat no- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland.'),1 )
from dual )
```

Comment: This answer is entirely code with no explanation of what assumptions you have made about the data, how you are solving the issue or why it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *regexp_substr()* if you data may similar kind.

As Per the Post I found some Similarity in your desired output like:

1. It start with `Flat no`
2. End with `digit`
3. and may Contain only one special symbol `/`

So based on that you may create Regular expression

`Flat no[A-z -]+[0-9/]+`

Which able to match specific substring

```
SELECT 
regexp_substr('Abc.. Flat no - 8956, 8th road ,
 Scramendo 4th street,Portland','Flat no[A-z -]+[0-9/]+') AS output FROM dual;

SELECT 
regexp_substr('Abcd.. Flat no Ad- 3434/89/69 Scramendo 4th street,Portland',
'Flat no[A-z -]+[0-9/]+') AS output FROM dual;
```

output:

```
Flat no - 8956
Flat no Ad- 3434/89/69
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=122dd68ca441edc36085d4ada5cd347c)

Comment: This answer is entirely code with no explanation of what assumptions you have made about the data, how you are solving the issue or why it works.

Comment: Sir answer is simple use appropriate regular expression so I thought there is no need to explanation.

Comment: I looked at the other answer and had to spend several minutes deciphering what the code did so I left a comment on it. Then I looked at your code and saw, although your code was much simpler (and better), that exactly the same comment applied to your code; so out of fairness, I have left exactly the same comment. It may be simple code but you should still try to explain what it does.